# Remove Backslash Escaping in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, backslash

I have a pretty complex problem.

I'm using PHP to parse a CSV file to an array and then

```
var array = <?php echo json_encode( $array ) ?>;
```

to pass it to the Javascript `array`.

`array` is 2-dimensional, like so:

```
var array = [["\/\\ssa","14104","26","2113","0","867","28083","15","43695"],
             ["Yee","8661","24","2215","0","991","25245","15","49086"],...]
```

Now sometimes there seems to be a problem with backslash escapes in the username when it is structured like this:

["username\","sth","sth",...], so when the username ends with a backslash \ .

The output will be:

```
username", sth, sth, ...
```

But this is only the first element of the sub-array, the other 8 places are empty.

I have already tried to fix it with a loop replace, but I don't know how to add \" as search value. Is this impossible to do in JS since \" always escapes? Already tried charAt() to compare the last character with the backslash, but no success. Do I have to replace it before passing it to JS, in PHP?
The Parse function is this, if it's important:

```
<?php>

$url = "data.csv";
$csvData = file_get_contents($url);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
$array[] = str_getcsv($line);

?>
```

**Here a JSfiddle you can play with:** https://jsfiddle.net/cLmbe0qf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to replace backslashes by an html special character :

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $line = str_replace("\\", "&#92;", $line);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit more tricky since you have to parse the javascript into an object/array. Anytime you do this, the backslash is parsed out. To avoid doing this you need to store the value in the HTML page or use [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) to get the literal version of the string.

One way to implement it is to put the the string in the html and get the value of a hidden textarea. (you could store it anywhere, i just chose textarea). You then pass it through this javascript function `slashParse` which will replace all slashes with `~{}~` then run the javascript parsing algorithm, then replace the `~{}~` back to the backslashes.

```js
function slashParse(target) {
  var value = document.getElementById(target).value;
  var replacedVal = value.replace(/\\/g, '~{}~');
  var parsedVal = JSON.parse(replacedVal);
  var mappedVal = parsedVal.map(function(item) {
    return item.replace(/~{}~/g, '\\');
  });
  return mappedVal;
}
var parsed = slashParse('input');
console.log(parsed)
document.getElementById("test").innerText = parsed;
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>
<textarea style="display:none" id="input">["use\rna&lt;/textarea&gt;&lt;textarea&gt;me\\","2","3","4"]</textarea>
```

What echoing it out onto the page might look like would be like this.

```
<textarea style="display:none" id="php-part">
  <?=json_encode(htmlentities($array,ENT_NOQUOTES))?>
</textarea>
```

This is only one solution of a few more. Another option is to do more parsing on the php side of things. The problem you will run into, is that at some point you need to run the string through the JavaScript parsing program. When that happens you cannot have any backslashes. Then after you run it through the parsing, you will have to convert all hidden backslashes back to backslashes.

The one problem with this method is that if there is anywhere EVER where `~{}~` is being placed in the string, it will be converted to backslashes afterwards. Something you can do in order to make it more aloof is to make the string backslashes get turn into even more obfuscated. Such as `~{BACKSLASH_ESCAPE}~`